# Android: auto resize text inside circle

Tags: android

I have a TextView which has a circle as a background. I want to auto size number inside it so that it will not go out of circle:
Following is my TextView:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12345"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

following is my circle_background.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <stroke android:color="#F5F5F5" android:width="5dip"/>
    <solid android:color="#F5F5F5"/>
</shape>
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/autosizing-textview.html

Answer (score 0):

With Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can instruct a TextView to let the text size expand or contract automatically to fill its layout based on the TextView's characteristics and boundaries. This setting makes it easier to optimize the text size on different screens with dynamic content.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

**Example:**

Add the following attributes to your textView to change the textSize on runtime.

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="22sp"
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use new appcompat function.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

```xml
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
  android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
  android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
  android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
/>
```

The important part which allows you to define min/max font size to resize and step to automatic change font size:

```xml
  android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
  android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
  android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
  android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
```

You will still be able to use your part with:

```xml
android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
android:gravity="center"
```

Just set some little padding for `TextView` to make proper font size to circle.

Comment: Please expand your answer with a) how to use this feature b) how to get the 26.0.0-beta2 support library. Basically your answer needs to be good enough in case I can't access the source.